# What is the best alternative to null in object oriented programming?

Tags: oop, object

I don't feel satisfied by [avoiding null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) in OOP.
Is there any alternative solution?
I don't like to avoid it in  [this way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) either.

What is the best possible way to handle it?

Comment: don't let things be NULL?!?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid null values?  Null isn't a bad thing.

Comment: consider Optional (Java 8)

Comment: [Guava optional: Using and avoiding null](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained).

Comment: You can make an object with a method body that is empty... Which is essentially the same thing with more code...

Comment: How that can be achieved. Can you elaborate @Mitch Wheat.

Comment: The main problem with null is that it's a value to indicate the abscence of a value!

Answer (score 9):

Java 8 has the new [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) type which is what I think you are asking about

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a value is present, `isPresent()` will return true and `get()` will return the value.

Comment: Just be aware it's not `Serializable`.

Comment: @Greg Kopff, that is a language dependent solution. Actually i want solution from design point of view.

Comment: Guava has `Optional` too. This may be useful if you are still stuck with java 7.

Comment: @user2749218 it may be language dependent, but you tagged the question with Java...

Comment: Actually i want framework/language independent solution.

Comment: Something like `Optional` is not specific to Java, in fact many functional programming languages have something similar (Haskell `Maybe`, Scala `Option`, ML `Option` etc). Java 8 borrowed it from those languages.

Comment: @user2749218 The Wikipedia entry on the [Option Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) might be helpful then.

Answer (score 2):

Although you don't like it, the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) is one of the best ways to avoid null. Also never return null when you could return an empty list.

Comment: Most often seen example of the null object pattern is the empty string "".  Use it when you have to say something but you want to say nothing : )

Comment: Hehe, nice explenation :-)

Answer (score 2):

I favour adding a static class property of Empty. This returns a specific value for the object which can be compared against - like string.Empty in .NET