# check if variable null in declaring function in php5

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have this code when I declaring function  I have check if variable null or not null

with this code I have problem :

```
private function addDepartementField(FormInterface $form, ?Region $region) { .... }
```

problem is :

> Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

how to use ? in php 5 , I use php 5.6

thanks advanced

Comment: show your php 5.6 version code

Comment: About the best you can do with PHP 5.6 I think would be something like `private function addDepartmentField(FormInterface $form = null, Region $region = null) { ... }` - by giving it a default value of `null` you can pass `null` through as a parameter... or just leave it out of the method call all together of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible in PHP 5.6. It's a new feature in **PHP7.1**. That's why you get this error.

> Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark. This signifies that as well as the specified type, NULL can be passed as an argument, or returned as a value, respectively. http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

## Update

The only things are removing the `?`, setting `$region` default to null (`Region $region = null`) or upgrading to `PHP7.*`.
If you remove the `?`, you have to pass a `Region` instance. That's in my opinion a better choice: **avoiding null** ([What is the best alternative to null in object oriented programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395397/what-is-the-best-alternative-to-null-in-object-oriented-programming)).

Comment: So what is the solution in my example ??

Comment: See my updated answer. I recommend avoiding null.